# retrieving local directory from perforce in python

Tags: python, path, perforce

If I have a python script in which it connects to the user perforce.  What command could i use where I give it the perforce path ex-(//perforce/path) and get back the local path on that persons machine? ex-(C:/p4/perforce/path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

`p4 where //perforce/path/...`

This will return output like:

`//perforce/path/... //myclient/perforce/path/... C:/p4/perforce/path/...`

i.e. you'll get the depot path, the client namespace path, and the local filesystem path.  The client's `View` maps depot to client, and the client's `Root` maps client to local.

Note that it is possible for different subsets of the path to be mapped to different locations, in which case you'll get multiple lines of output.  (Or the path might not be mapped at all locally, in which case you'll get an error.)